# How do I create uncertainty color map image from deep CNN output?

Tags: neural-network, statistics, deep-learning, probability, conv-neural-network

I am designing a deep CNN classifiers for urban features detection. Most of time my network classifies and segment out building properly but many time it gets confused due to illumination / similar appearance etc. with other objects.

I want to create a color map along with segmented image that can represent how certain classifier is? I have used softmaxwith loss for training network.

```
layer {
  name: "score"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "pool_3"
  top: "score"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    bias_term: false
    pad:2
    kernel_size: 8
    stride: 4
  }
}
```

I am expecting output similar to this color map image:

[image: color map image]

My issues are

1. How to calculate uncertainty?
2. How to handle negative values while calculating uncertainty?

Note: Currently, I am able to get color map using entropy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to perform an *occlusion sensitivity experiment* that allows to build a heat map of most important image areas.

From [this answer on AI StackExchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/do-scientists-know-what-is-happening-inside-artificial-neural-networks/4044#4044):

> Here's the idea. Suppose that a ConvNet classifies an image as a dog. How can we be certain that it’s actually picking up on the dog in the image as opposed to some contextual cues from the background or some other miscellaneous object?
>
> One way of investigating which part of the image some classification prediction is coming from is by plotting the probability of the class of interest (e.g. dog class) as a function of the position of an occluder object. If we iterate over regions of the image, replace it with all zeros and check the classification result, we can build a 2-dimensional heat map of what's most important for the network on a particular image.

[image]